# encryption/decryption of one time password in python

Tags: python, encryption

how to encrypt one time password using the public key and again recover it by the private key of the user  , i need to do it using python

Comment: Do you want to encrypt something using a one-time key or do you want to encrypt the one-time key itself? Please clarify. 

And if you mean an one-time pad you shouldn't have to use a complex encryption algo at all, just use XOR. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_pad

Comment: You should provide more detail on you application. Crypto things tend to go bad unless you know the "big picture" when designing them. Solving basic task with a key-hole view often leads to brittle solutions.

Comment: i want to encrypt one time password itself using the public key of the user which i retrieve from the server and also want to decrypt it using private key of the same user .i need to do it in python.

Answer (score 4):

You can use Python's encryption library called PyCrypto (www.pycrypto.org). Here's some overview of Public Key encryption using PyCrypto: http://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/doc/#crypto-publickey-public-key-algorithms

Answer (score 0):

Use an encryption library, for example [`pyopenssl`](https://launchpad.net/pyopenssl), which looks more up-to-date then `pycrypto`.

> `pyopenssl` is a rather thin wrapper around (a subset of) the OpenSSL
>      library. With thin wrapper I mean that a lot of the object methods do
>      nothing more than calling a corresponding function in the OpenSSL
>      library.